# Finding index using switch case statement in javascript

Tags: indexing, switch-statement, kettle, e4x, pentaho-spoon

I'm using Pentaho(ETL) tool to achieve the output using a javascript component which accepts javascript code to achieve the desired transformation.The following table is imported into pentaho from a .csv file(source file). 
For example this is my table structure

```
 +--------+--------+--------+
| RLD    | MD     | INC    |
+--------+--------+--------+
|      0 |   3868 | 302024 |
|  53454 |   7699 | 203719 |
| 154508 |    932 |  47694 |
| 107547 |  36168 |  83592 |
```

I want to use a script which would give me the max_value and its index number, such that my output would look like
**Output Table**

```
 +--------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
    | RQD    | MT     | IZC    | max_value | max_index |
    +--------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
    |      0 |   3868 | 302024 |    302024 |         3 |
    |  53454 |   7699 | 203719 |   203719  |         3 |
    | 154508 |    932 |  47694 |    154508 |         1 |
    |    456 |  107547|  83592 |    107547 |         2 |
```

To get the max value from rows I have used

```
var max_value = Math.max(RQD,MT,IZC);
println(max_value);
```

I tried to get their index using the following script

```
var max_index = switch (Math.max(RQD,MT,IZC))
           {
           case "RQD":document.write("1")
           case "MT":document.write("2")
           case "MT":document.write("3")
         default:document.write("0") 

       }
```

How can I get the desired result in the form of javascript data structure? Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Please explain what is inside the *RQD*,*MT* and *IZC* variables.

Comment: all variable contains numbers(integers) stored in tabular format

Comment: Your switch is wrong as you should put a string not the max value. You should have a structure and check the max value by yourself, to save the column and the index.

Comment: Edits have been made to post,please check

Comment: You should add how you get the variables with the record values. As I see you post just how you handle the data of a single record. And more, you didn't say how the results should appear: an html table? a javascript data structure? Something else?

Comment: wish to see the result in javascript data structure

Comment: please update your question with this infos. That made things easiest for who want to help.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini edits done

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code, lets solve them!

- Use breaks: you must use breaks in order to avoid the switch moving to cases below its match.
- switch cases do not return a value like functions, you cannot use a switch return to define a variable, you need to define the variable inside the switch case.
- Math.max does not return the name of its maximum variable, instead it returns the maximum `number` from its given parameters.

to solve this issue, i would not use a switch case with math.max to be honest, however to answer your question:

```
var tableArray = [RQD,MT,IZC];
var maxIndex = tableArray.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, arr));
if(maxIndex > -1) document.write(maxIndex+1);
```

- i used +1 because you have your index in the example table starting from 1 instead of 0.
- the way the array is sorted should match the way the table is sorted per raw.

Comment: Edits have been made to post,please check

Comment: removed the println bullet point, try my code it should solve your case without a switch case.

Comment: That's a weird behaviour of Kettle. Apparently, output of functions are not instanceof Number, while array elements injected from Kettle are Numbers.
Following code works for some reason:
`var tableArray = [RQD, MT, IZC].map(Number); 
var maxResult = Math.max.apply(null, tableArray); 
var maxIndex = tableArray.indexOf(maxResult);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = [
{RLD:0,
MD:3868,
INC:302024
},
{RLD:53454,
MD:7699,
INC:203719
},
{RLD:154508,
MD:932,
INC:47694
},
{RLD:107547,
MD:36168,
INC:83592
},
];

list = list.map(function(item){
  var keys = Object.keys(item);
  item.max_value = item[keys[0]];
  item.max_index = '';
  for(var i = 1, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    var keyValue = item[key];
    if (item.max_value < keyValue){
      item.max_value = keyValue;
      item.max_index = key;
    }
  }
  return item;
})
```

Comment: Edits have been made to post,please check

Comment: ,the variable values are not be be entered manually, can we not just consider the column only.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could not solve this problem with a *switch* statement.

In a javascript *switch* you should provide a value that is one of the followed *case*(s), otherwise the *switch* will go to the *default* if defined.

Your problem seems to be to find out the higher value of 3 columns and print out, the colums row by row adding a column with the max value and the index of the column where you found it.

So for example on the row:

1, RLD : 0

2, MD : 3868

3, INC : 302024

In this case the higher value is *INC* with the column index *3*.

If you have just the variables with the number values, you could do nothing more than something like this:

```
function getMaxValueRow (RLD, MD, INC) {

    var max_value = RLD;
    var max_index = 1;

    if (MD > max_value) {
        max_value = MD;
        max_index = 2;
    }

    if (INC > max_value) {
        max_value = INC;
        max_index = 3;
    }

    return [RLD, MD, INC, max_value, max_index];
}
```

You could return an object too like this:

```
retrun {
    'RQD': RLD,
    'MT': MD,
    'IZC': INC,
    'max_value': max_value,
    'max_index': max_index
}
```